# How to write if statement in arrow function expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i am not getting expected result in below code just wanted to know if its correct way to add condition in arrow function syntax using expression.

```js
const drugPriceErrors = [99, 85];

Case#1 
const messages = [{
  settlementCode: "99",
  settlementDesc: "test:test"
}]

Case#2 
const messages = [{
  settlementCode: "77",
  settlementDesc: "test"
}
];

Case#3 

const messages = [{
  settlementCode: "66",
  settlementDesc: "test:test"
}]


function validateEntries(messages) {
  if (!messages) {
    return []
  };

  let filteredMsg = messages.filter((item) => {
    if (!drugPriceErrors.includes(item.settlementCode)) {
      item.settlementDesc.includes(":")
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });

  return filteredMsg;
};

console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

expected output

```
Case#1 output should be 
    [{
      settlementCode: "99",
      settlementDesc: "test:test"
    }]

Case#2 output should be 

[]

Case#3 output 

[{
      settlementCode: "66",
      settlementDesc: "test:test"
    }]
```

Comment: From the `filter()` you are returning `undefined`(falsy value) all the time. Use return `true` when you want to includes item in result array otherwise return `false`

Comment: Arrow functions don't have implicit returns when you give them a body. `item.settlementDesc.includes(":")` needs to be `return item.settlementDesc.includes(":")`.

Comment: `.filter(item => !drugPriceErrors.includes(item.settlementCode) && item.settlementDesc.includes(":"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to filter in those objects that meet following criteria

- `SettlementCode` should not exist in `drugPriceErrors` array **OR**
- `SettlementDesc` should contain `:`

You can correct your code as following

- Firstly, as `drugPriceErrors` is an array of numbers, convert `settlementCode` to number using `+settlementCode`
- If condition is evaluated to true i.e. `settlementCode` exist in `drugPriceErrors`, return true
- Else, return whether `settlementDesc` contains `:`

```js
const drugPriceErrors = [99,85];
const messages = [ {settlementCode:"99", settlementDesc: "test:test" }, {settlementCode:"66", settlementDesc: "test:test" },{settlementCode: "77",settlementDesc: "test"}];

function validateEntries(messages) {
  if (!messages) {
    return []
  };

  let filteredMsg = messages.filter((item) => {
    if (drugPriceErrors.includes(+item.settlementCode)) return true;
    else return item.settlementDesc.includes(":");
  });

  return filteredMsg;
};

console.log(validateEntries(messages));
```

Additionally, you can also simplify your code as following

```js
const drugPriceErrors = [99,85];
const messages = [ {settlementCode:"99", settlementDesc: "test:test" }, {settlementCode:"66", settlementDesc: "test:test" },{settlementCode: "77",settlementDesc: "test"}];   
    
 const result = messages.filter(v => drugPriceErrors.includes(+v.settlementCode) || v.settlementDesc.includes(":"));
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes i want to check first if settlementCode exist return same array that was passed it should filter or vice versa if settlementCOde does not exist that filter logic should apply, in a case if there is one message and settlementCode exist

Comment: `If settlementCode exist return same array` can you please clarify?

Comment: ok if messages are `[ {settlementCode:"99", settlementDesc: "test:test" }]` what would validateEntries return it should return this object

Comment: Still not clear. Can you explain on the reason behind expected output in question

Comment: there are two scenarios actually if settlementCode exist it should not filter array return array as it was passed and if settlementCode does not exist and message contain ":" then apply filter and return the object

Comment: Okay. So in quesiton, settlementCode `99` existed even then you did return the complete array and filtered it

Comment: how not to filter 99 settlementCode exist

Comment: What is the expected output - `[ {settlementCode:"99", settlementDesc: "test:test" }, {settlementCode:"66", settlementDesc: "test:test" }, {settlementCode:"18", settlementDesc: "test:test" }, {settlementCode:"85", settlementDesc: "testing" }]`

Comment: added 3 cases for more understanding and expected ouput

Comment: Right. The above solution honors all the 3 cases.

Comment: `messages.filter(v => drugPriceErrors.includes(+v.settlementCode` what does `+v` mean in the code

Comment: It is converting `v.settlementCode` to a number. It is required because `drugPriceErrors` is an array of numbers whereas `v.settlementCode` is a String.